# How to make the text font shrink and match JTextArea height?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, fontmetrics

I have a JTextArea that receives a text, but the problem is when the text is too long it doesn't fit and the scroll bar appears. What i want is to automatically shrink the font size to match The JTextArea height. 
[image: Right now its like this]

Comment: look for `java.awt.FontMetrics` class , it will do the job.

Comment: *"but the problem is when the text is too long it doesn't fit and the scroll bar appears"* That's a feature, not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use below method, (update max and min size's according to your requirement)

```
public static int getMatchingFontSize(JComponent comp, String string) {
    int minSize = 10;
    int maxSize = 60;
    Dimension size = comp.getSize();

    if (comp == null || comp.getFont() == null || string.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    //Init variables
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;

    Font font = comp.getFont();
    int curSize = font.getSize();
    FontMetrics fm = comp.getFontMetrics(new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), maxSize));
    while (fm.stringWidth(string) + 4 > width || fm.getHeight() > height) {
        maxSize--;
        fm = comp.getFontMetrics(new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), maxSize));
        curSize = maxSize;
    }
    while (fm.stringWidth(string) + 4 < width || fm.getHeight() < height) {
        minSize++;
        fm = comp.getFontMetrics(new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), minSize));
        curSize = minSize;
    }
    if (curSize < minSize) {
        curSize = minSize;
    }
    if (curSize > maxSize) {
        curSize = maxSize;
    }
    return curSize;
}
```